# Minimax estimation rate of sparse vector $w_\star$, w.r.t to mixed norm $\|\hat w_n-w_\star\| := \|\hat w_n - w_\star\|_2 + \|\hat w_n-w_\star\|_q$

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-concentration, compressed-sensing

Let $n,d,s$ be positive integers with $s \le d$, and let $B_0(d,s)$ be the set of all (real) $d$-dimensional vectors with at most $s$ nonzero components. Given an $n \times d$ matrix $X$ with rows $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, a vector $w_\star \in \mathbb R^d$, and  iid $\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, form labels

$$
y_i := x_i^\top w + \epsilon,\text{ for }i=1,2,\ldots,n,
$$

and consider a dataset $D_n := \{(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)\}$. Note that $D_n$ is random due to randomness in the $\epsilon_i$'s. The goal is to estimate $w_\star$ from the dataset $D_n$. Let $\hat A$ be any algorithm which consumes this dataset an outputs a possible random vector $\hat w_n := \hat A(D_n) \in \mathbb R^d$. Finally, let $\alpha \ge 0$ and $q \ge 1$, and define

$$
\Delta(n,d,s,q,\alpha,X) := \inf_{\hat A}\sup_{w_\star \in B_0(d,s)}\mathbb E\,\alpha \|\hat w_n - w_\star\|_2 + \|\hat w_n-w_\star\|_q.
$$

**Question.** What is a good lower-bound for $\Delta(n,d,s,q,\alpha,X)$ ?

I'm particularly interested in the case $q=1$.

### Very rough estimate

Define $\theta(X,s) \ge 0$ by

$$
\theta(X,s) := \sup_{\delta \in B_0(d,s),\,\delta \ne 0} \frac{\|X\delta\|_2}{\sqrt{n}\|\delta\|_2}.
$$

It was shown in [Theorem 7.1, Bellec et al. 2018](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08651.pdf) that if $s \le d/2$, then

$$
\Delta(n,d,s,q,0,X) \gtrsim \frac{\psi(n,d,s,q)}{\theta(X,1)},\text{ with }\psi(n,d,s,q) := \sigma s^{1/q}\sqrt{\dfrac{\log(ed/s)}{n}}.
$$
We deduce that

$$
\begin{split}
\Delta(n,d,s,q,\alpha,X) &\ge \max(\alpha\Delta(n,d,s,2,0,X), \Delta(n,d,s,q,0,X))\\
& \gtrsim \frac{\max(\alpha\psi(n,d,s,2),\psi(n,d,s,q))}{\theta(X,1)}\\
&\asymp \frac{\sigma}{\theta(X,1)}\sqrt{\frac{\log(ed/s)}{n}}\cdot \begin{cases}
\alpha \sqrt{s},&\mbox{ if }\alpha = \Omega(1),\\
s^{1/q},&\mbox{ else.}
\end{cases}
\end{split}
$$

However, by construction, the dependence on $\alpha$ and $q$ in the above is likely to be very sub-optimal in general.

Answer (score 0):

For any $c \ge 0$, define $\theta(s,c)$ by
\begin{eqnarray}
\theta(X,s,c) := \inf_{\delta \in \mathrm{CRE}(s,c)}\dfrac{\|X\delta\|_2}{\sqrt{n}\|\delta\|_2},
\end{eqnarray}

where $\mathrm{CRE}(s,c) := \{\delta \in \mathbb R^d \mid 0 < \|\delta\|_1 \le (1+c)\sqrt{s}\|\delta\|_2\}$.

Using corollary 4.3 of [Bellec et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08651.pdf), one can easily establish that

> **Theorem.** *If $\overline \theta(X,1) \le 1$ and $\theta(X,s,7) > 0$, then the lower-bound obtained in the original question is tight: it is obtained by a Lasso estimator with the usual tuning $\lambda \asymp \sigma \sqrt{\dfrac{\log(2ed/s)}{n}}$.*

This solves my problem completely.